# Playback in Video Sequencer is too fast

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When I hit play animation (alt A) from the video sequencer, the video plays at about three times the normal speed (even though it says it's playing at 60 fps it's really playing much faster.  any ideas?

Comment: What frame rate is the original video? What frame rate are you using in the blender project? Is this a recording done from a computer? Is the recording using any form of variable frame rate?

Comment: Sometimes a screen recording will have a variable frame rate and Blender cannot decompress it correctly. Try converting to a Blender friendly Codec.